# Dynamically setting the field width in printf formatting string

Tags: java, format

I'm trying to print out a tabular representation of the 8puzzle game.

I know how to use print formatting, i.e. `printf("%2s", ..)` etc. etc., but am unsure how to allow this to change depending on the size of the board being played (perhaps 3x3, 5x5, ...).

I can obtain the length of the maximum number by coding:

```
String.valueOf(Side*Side - 1).length()
```

and store that in an int. How would I then get that int to replace the 2 in the printf example above?

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried constructing the template string dynamically? That should get you the proper template for output.

Comment: "Is there a better way to do this?"  
What are you looking for when you say *better*?

Comment: Turns out I don't need to change the tabular representation based off of the input size of the board -- the requirements wanted me to format the board using %3s. Still a good thing to learn.

Can you clarify what you mean, @DavisBroda. How would one do that?

Comment: @rageandqq I meant better as in more concise, clear, efficient. I was thinking in terms of using something like StringBuilder (which I've never used but have read a bit about).

Answer (score 0):

To get the integer as your field length in the format, just concatenate it as part of the string:

```
int maxWidth = String.valueOf(Side*Side - 1).length();
printf( "%" + maxWidth + "s", .... );
```

The formatting string is a string like any other.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to dynamically construct a template String, and put everything into there. For instance, for a 3x3 board you might want the template `"%n\t%n\t%n\n%n\t%n\t%n\n%n\t%n\t%n"`, which will print as a 3x3 grid on the console if supplied with 9 numeric inputs. In order to construct the template do the following:

```
public String makeTemplate(size){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0;i < size;i++){
        for(int i = 0;i < size-1;i++){
            builder.append("%n\t");
        }
        builder.append("%n\n");
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Use this the templates generated by a similar method to properly format your output. An example of usage is shown below

```
public void someMethod(){
    int[] numbers = new int[9]; //fill in array with numbers
    String template = makeTemplate(3);
    String formatted = String.format(template,numbers);
    System.out.println(formatted);
}
```

Comment: Gottchha! So using String.format(template, numbers), it will fill in the template %n locations with the numbers stored in numbers[ ]. Cool! Didn't know you could do that, thanks